# frontend migration from Adobe Flex to JavaScript/HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, air, cross-browser, porting

we are currently using Adobe Flex/AIR (Flash in browser, AIR for iOS and Android) as frontend for a business application. The backend is based on MySQL/PHP and ZendAMF. The communication between the frontend and the backend is done by RemoteObject.

We are now planing to update our browser-frontend to JavaScript/HTML/CSS and use Adobe AIR only for mobile apps (iOS and Android). The backend should stay the same if possible because we want to use it from browser and mobile.

Are there any best practice approaches to migrate from Adobe Flex/Flash to HTML/CSS?
Are there any stable AMF implementations for JavaScript which work cross-browser without problems?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I voted to close; as this is not a question that can be discretely answered, but more of a discussion style question.  The only JavaScript AMF implementation I have heard of was experimental.  I strongly suggest switching to JSON for HTML/JS stuff.  That will most likely require some backend changes; or building a new set of services.  In terms of "Best Practices" the answer is: "no, there are none."  Or "Best practices depend on a lot of factors; and you haven't shared any requirements so we can't point you in a direction"

Comment: I believe Ext.js has an AMF implementation (they made it precisely for this kind of scenario), but I have no idea what it's worth.

Comment: Haxe has an AMF0 implementation, it could be worth trying it and publishing it to JS

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am author of Atoms.js

Look at image and tell me if looks different then flex. In any other framework you will end up writing lots of script, where in flex you had advantage of creating mark up. We wanted to move out of flex and so we had to create our own framework. FlexJS is still under development, where else our framework offers much more then flex and it is used in production.

This is a Sample of what all things are possible in Web Atoms JS.

Here is link to documentation.
http://webatomsjs.neurospeech.com/docs

[image: Flex to HTML]